# Prevent Visual Studio Code or IDE From Revealing Python Class Private Methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, methods, ide, private

just want to ask a quick question;

Essentially, I want to know if it's possible to hide Python class private methods from the list of suggestions that Visual Studio Code or other IDEs provide.

For instance, suppose that we have a class `"A"`:

```
# Creating a class
class A:

    # Declaring public method
    def fun(self):
        print("Public method")

    # Declaring private method
    def __fun(self):
        print("Private method")
    
    # Calling private method via
    # another method
    def Help(self):
        self.fun()
        self.__fun()
```

Now, we don't want Visual Studio Code or other IDEs to show the method `"__fun"` in the list of suggestions provided by the IDE, how can we do that?

I can see that even though `"__fun"` has been declared as private method inside class `"A"`, Visual Studio code will still suggest it in its snippet:

[image: Visual Studio Code Suggestion]

Would it be possible to get rid of this?

Comment: there are no private methods in Python, using `__` is a convention to show the user you should **not** use this method, it is not part of the API, if you want true hidden functions define a function inside a function, but you want to see them if you use `self.`, but what if you rename `self` to `me`

Comment: @rioV8 Appreciate the reply mate. Ah right I see, yeah I heard about it that apparently Python does not have a `"true"` private method and the double underscore `"__"` prefix is just a convention that can be used to imitate the behaviour of a private method. 

However, I don't quite understand what you said about `"self"` and `"me"`. I don't even know that there's a keyword `"me"` in Python. I know `"self"` is a variable which contains the instance of a class but I don't know what `"me"` is.

Comment: `self` is also a convention to use, you can name the first argument anything, in class methods the convention is to use `cls`, but it is not mandatory, if you search replace `self` for `me` it all still works

Comment: @rioV8 Ohhh I didn't know that . Well, I've learned something new thanks to you! So about that last sentence in your comment `"but you want to see them if you use self., but what if you rename self to me "`, you're saying that basically the double underscore is just a way to let users know that they shouldn't use the method, correct? Thanks again mate!

Comment: I mean you probably want these functions shown if you write the class methods, otherwise you have to type the name in full, and then you start using very short names and you forget after a few months what the function does

Comment: @rioV8 Right I see, thanks so much for the help mate!

Answer (score 1):

**I may have found a partial solution to your question, which may help**

There is a python language setting in vscode that, if enabled, reports an usage of 'protected' function (started with underscore) outside of the class.

Press CTRL+SHIFT+P, type "Configure Language Specific Settings" and select Python. In JSON object add the following property:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportPrivateUsage": "error"
}
```

[image: Error reporting when private function is called from outside of the class]

source: [code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate private methods using a method registration class but it will require tagging both the private methods and the public methods that are allowed to access them:

```
class PrivateMethods:

    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = dict()

    def __call__(self,f):    
        name = inspect.getsource(f).split("def ",1)[-1]
        name = name.split("(")[0].strip()
        self.methods[name]=f              # register private method
        del(f)                            # and remove it from class

    def access(self,f):
        def withAccess(obj,*args,**kwargs):
            obj.__inPrivate += 1                  # internal depth counter
            try: result = f(obj,*args,**kwargs)   # around public calls
            finally: obj.__inPrivate -= 1         
            return result
        return withAccess

    def method(self,instance,name):
        if name == '_PrivateMethods__inPrivate': return 0
        if name in self.methods and instance.__inPrivate:
            f = self.methods[name]
            return lambda *args,**kwargs:f(instance,*args,**kwargs)
        else: 
            raise AttributeError(f'{type(instance)} has no {name} attribute')
```

You class will need to have an instance of PrivateMethods to hold the names and code of the private methods outside of the class itself.  By defining the `__getattr__` to access the private methods, you prevent any use of these methods outside of the class's code.  The PrivateMethods object stores the name and code of private methods. It also removes them from the class (after being defined).

With this, you don't need to use the double underline naming convention to hide private methods (although it is still a good practice to do so)

Usage:

```
class myClass:

    # boiler plate code to use in your class
    private = PrivateMethods()         
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return myClass.private.method(self,name)

    def privMethod(self,a):                        
        print('in private',a,type(self)) 
    private(privMethod)                   # register/remove private
    
    @private.access                       # allow access to privates
    def pubMethod(self):
        self.privMethod("from pubMethod")

c = myClass()
c.pubMethod()
# in private from pubMethod <class '__main__.myClass'>

c.privMethod("from outside")
# AttributeError: <class '__main__.myClass'> has no privMethod attribute
```

Comment: Let me remark that your post does not provide a solution to the original question of how to hide methods that start with underscore. Is would be very helpful to not see all default methods and properties (same for all python classes) in the hint box, like \_\_dir\_\_, for example